# how to check user role from wordpress in a angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, wordpress, typescript

I'm setting up angular application inside a wordpress theme. Some Angular elements should check if a user is logged in and have a specific role to show some content. Wordpress is a PHP cms system and Angular is based on typescript. How to archive this.

What I am able to do is.

```
 console.log(document.body.classList.contains( 'logged-in' ));
```

But it seems very unsafe and its just the login status and has no user role check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in PHP data to JavaScript using [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script):

```
function so61079973_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Register the script
    wp_register_script( 'your-script', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

    // Get the user object.
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

    // Get all the user roles as an array.
    $user_roles = $user->roles;

    // Localize the script with new data
    $data_array = array(
        'is_logged_in' => is_user_logged_in(),
        'user_roles' => json_encode( $user_roles )
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'your-script', 'user_data', $data_array );

    // Enqueued script with localized data.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'your-script' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so61079973_enqueue_scripts');
```

Then, in the JavaScript, you can get the data by calling the `user_data` object:

```
user_data.is_logged_in
user_data.user_roles
```